# Update <p> value when typing in input field

Tags: javascript, input

I am building a simple chrome plugin that will automatically update the value in an `input` field.

There is an `element` (let's say a `<p>` tag) that gets updated when the value of the input field changes.

The problem I am having is I can easily update the input field value using `myInputField.value = "20"` and this shows up properly on the form. However, the value of the `<p>` does not get updated according. It only gets updated when I actually type into the input field.

I'm guessing there is some event listener there which is looking for some sort of `keydown` or `change` or something along those lines, but I am not sure which one it is and I don't have access to the code anyways.

Is there a solution to this? I tried a few things using the following, but it doesn't work.

```
const EVENT_OPTIONS = {bubbles: true, cancelable: false, composed: true};
const EVENTS = {
    BLUR: new Event("blur", EVENT_OPTIONS),
    CHANGE: new Event("change", EVENT_OPTIONS),
    INPUT: new Event("input", EVENT_OPTIONS),
};

const inputElement = document.getElementById("myInputField");
inputElement.value = "20%";
inputElement.dispatchEvent(EVENTS.CHANGE);
inputElement.dispatchEvent(EVENTS.INPUT);
```

For reference, here is a picture with the steps:

[image]

I type into the input field at `1` and then `2` and `3` are automatically updated. It works when I type in the field physically but when I simply set the value with JS, it doesn't update `2` and `3`.

Really appreciate some insights on this. Haven't found a solution after hours of research. Note: I need a  Vanilla JS solution as I cannot use jQuery on this one.

Comment: Event listeners such as `change` do *not* fire when the values are changed via code.  You need to trigger the event, or, easier, move your event handler to its own function and call it from both change handlers.

Comment: @freedomn-m That's the problem. I can't actually modify those event listeners. Essentially, I'm building a Chrome plugin that will auto-fill a form on Hubspot CRM

Comment: Your code should work in general.  How is mentioned  `p` element updated? If you dont have access to that code, you will have to update element manualy.

Comment: @JanPfeifer I did an inspection on the element (at `1`) and it turns out when I actually type into the input field, a POST request is made which updates the values at `2` and `3` in the picture above. Doing a simple `inputField.value = "20"` for example, updates the value but it's not executing the POST request like when I actually type in manually. So confusing

Comment: So you're saying some third-party code is doing the `element.value = `

Comment: @freedomn-m I'm doing the `element.value` in the input field st `1` in the picture. Then there is an ajax code running on input and content at `2` and `3` changes. I have no control over that code as it's internal to Hubspot. The problem is when I change the value at `1` using `element.value` , the value changes, but the values at `2` and `3` are not updated. They only get updated when I actually type physically into the input field at `1` using my keyboard. Hope that is more clear now

Comment: In jquery I would suggest `$("#id").val(newvalue).trigger("input")` see [youmightnotneedjquery](https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#trigger_native) for native equivalent - but there appears to be a typo there, so: `el.dispatchEvent(new Event("input", { bubbles:true })` (and/or `change` event - depends on what 3rd party code is listening for)